# Layering Queries

Tags: sql

I created a query to view the order of customers' purchase history, and want to build upon it based on the first purchase item to see if there are common ordering patterns.

I used the following partition by statement to determine the order and then added an inner join to find common 2nd purchase categories.

-- Query for Finding 2nd Purchase Product Category --

```
SELECT 
COUNT (DISTINCT "user_id") AS CUSTOMERS 
,"product_cateogry"
FROM (
       SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
             PARTITION BY GR."user_id"
             ORDER BY "event_date" ASC) AS PURCHASE_ORDER 
             ,GR."user_id"
             ,GR."product_category"
       FROM CUSTOMER_ORDERS AS GR
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT 
       "user_id"
       ,"product_category"
       FROM (
             SELECT 
             *,
             ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
             PARTITION BY "user_id"
             ORDER BY "event_date" ASC) AS PUR_O
             FROM CUSTOMER_ORDERS 
             QUALIFY PUR_O = 1) 
             WHERE "product_category" = 'purchase_1_cateogry' AND "event_date" > '2022-01-01 ) AS SR ON GR."user_id" = SR."user_id" 
WHERE GR."product_category" NOT IN ('purchase_1_category') AND "event_date" > '2022-01-01'
QUALIFY PURCHASE_ORDER = 1)
GROUP BY 
"product_cateogry"
ORDER BY 
CUSTOMERS DESC
;
```

I am getting stuck trying to determine the 3rd purchase and beyond. I've tried doing multiple joins (see below) on the same condition that "user_id' is the same, but it is not yielding the results I was intending. The 2nd inner join is pulling users who made a 2nd purchase in the respective category, but it's not joining the same users who also made a 1st purchase within the 1st purchase category originally outlined. Any ideas?

-- Attempted Query for 3rd Purchase Product Category --

```
SELECT 
COUNT (DISTINCT "user_id") AS CUSTOMERS 
,"product_category"
FROM (
      SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
          PARTITION BY "user_id"
          ORDER BY "event_date" ASC) AS PURCHASE_ORDER 
,GR."user_id"
,GR."product_category" 
FROM CUSTOMER ORDERS AS GR
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT 
       "user_id"
       ,"product_category"
       FROM ( 
             SELECT 
             *,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
            PARTITION BY  "user_id"
            ORDER BY "event_date" ASC) AS PUR_O
            FROM CUSTOMER_ORDERS
            QUALIFY PUR_O = 1) 
       WHERE "product_category" = 'purchase_1_category' AND "event_date" > '2022-01-01' ) AS SR ON GR."user_id" = SR."user_id"
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT 
      "user_id"
      ,"product_category"
           FROM (
                 SELECT 
                 *,
                 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
                 PARTITION BY "user_id"
                 ORDER BY "event_date" ASC) AS PUR_O
                 FROM CUSTOMER_ORDERS 
                 QUALIFY PUR_O = 2)
       WHERE "product_category" = 'purchase_2_category' AND "event_date" > '2022-01-01' ) AS BR ON GR."user_id" = BR."user_id" AND SR."user_id" = BR."user_id" 
WHERE GR."product_category" NOT IN ('purchase_1_category') AND GR."product_category" NOT IN ( 'purchase_2_category')
QUALIFY PURCHASE_ORDER = 1)
GROUP BY 
"product_category"
ORDER BY 
CUSTOMERS DESC
;
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: to clarify, only use the GR alias in the select statement?